# Apache Tika cannot detect MIME type properly

Tags: java, mime-types, apache-tika, file-extension

I am trying to detect file type while uploading a file usinn `Apache Tika` as shown below:

```
static final List<String> VALID_FILE_TYPES = Arrays.asList(

    // code omitted for brevity
    "audio/aac"
);



public static void detectFileType(InputStream inputStream, String fileId) {
    try {
        ApacheTika tika = new ApacheTika();
        String fileTypeFromFile = tika.detect(inputStream);
        
        if (!VALID_FILE_TYPES.contains(fileTypeFromFile)) {
            throw new IllegalFileUploadException("Illegal file type");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

For some file extensions e.g. `*.acc`, Apache Tika detect file type as `application/octet-stream`.

So, in this situation:

**1.** Is there a solution to detect some file types properly (e.g. `*.acc`) and get their exact file types like `audio/aac` ?

**2.** If there is not a solution, should I add `application/octet-stream` to my `VALID_FILE_TYPES` in order to accept `audio/aac`, etc. files?

Comment: Pass in the file name as well?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Either https://tika.apache.org/2.5.0/api/org/apache/tika/Tika.html#detect(java.io.File) or https://tika.apache.org/2.5.0/api/org/apache/tika/Tika.html#detect(java.io.InputStream,java.lang.String)

Comment: @Gravier Thanks, but detect method is not seem to be solution. I am thinking to use Tika Parser  as mentioned on metadata. So you have any idea or suggestion?

Comment: What isn't working when you pass the filename along with the content to Detect?

Comment: Could you please see this page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74028332/apache-tika-cannot-detect-aac-files-properly

Comment: Don't ask the same question a second time! Instead edit your existing question to have the additional details in it

Comment: And still, pass Tika the filename when your call detection with an `InputStream` to get the answer you expect!

Comment: What do you mean with `fileName`?

Comment: The name of the file that was uploaded

Comment: I tried, but `tika.detect(file.getInputStream(), file.getName());` returns `application/octet-stream`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Solved adding another Tika dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-parsers-standard-package</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Make sure it has the same version as the Tika Core library. I also had to pass the file name as well as @Gagravarr suggested