# Apache Tika cannot detect aac files properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, mime-types, apache-tika

I am trying to get the file type / mime type of a file while uploading and I use `Apache Tika` library. According to [this](https://tika.learnworlds.com/mime-types#audio/32kadpcm) page, files with the extension of `aac` is already supported by `Apache Tika`. However, I always get `application/octet-stream` as a file type by using the following approaches.

I also tried to use Tika Parsers, but cannot obtain file type of aac files properly:

**Detecting Document Types**

```
public static String detectDocTypeUsingDetector(InputStream stream) 
  throws IOException {
    Detector detector = new DefaultDetector();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

    MediaType mediaType = detector.detect(stream, metadata);
    return mediaType.toString();
}
```

```
// returns application/octet-stream
```

**Extracting Content**

```
public static String extractContentUsingParser(InputStream stream) 
  throws IOException, TikaException, SAXException {
 
    Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();

    parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context);
    return handler.toString();
}
```

```
// returns ""
```

**Extracting Content**

```
public static String extractContentUsingParser(InputStream stream) 
  throws IOException, TikaException, SAXException {
 
    Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();

    parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context);
    return handler.toString();
}
```

```
// returns "resourceName=name"
```

So, how can I get the content type for `aac` files properly?

Comment: Either use https://tika.apache.org/2.5.0/api/org/apache/tika/Tika.html#detect(java.io.InputStream,java.lang.String) or set the filename on the `Metadata` object before you call detect?

Comment: What do you mean with fileName? I get the file as MultipartFile and then when I look into it there is a location in Tomcat. Actually I do not want to use a  temp location and if it is possible to convert MultipartFile to File without writing to disk, the problem may be solved. But as far as I see and try the answers on SO, I cannot convert the MultipartFile to File. Any idea?

Comment: The name of the file that was uploaded to you. You don't need to convert any types, just grab the name of the file and hand that to Tika!